# OpenMP complex data visibility between threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

As far as I understand the following statement in OpenMP 3.1 spec (2.8.6)

> A flush construct without a list, executed on a given thread, operates as if the whole **thread-visible data state** of the program, as defined by the base language, is flushed.

means, that if any thread manipulates complex data (such as an array or a struct, or even an int, through a pointer variable) we can't be sure any other thread will see modifications made, when we use flush'es (either explicit or implicit).

Found the following citation:

> A flush without a list of variable names flushes all **variables** visible at that point
>   in the program. A flush with a list flushes only the variables in the list.
>   ... The OpenMP **flush** operation is **the only way** in an OpenMP program, to **guarantee**
>   that a value will move between two threads.

Taken from: J.P. Hoeflinger, B.R. De Supinski, The OpenMP memory model // Proceedings of the IWOMP’05/IWOMP’06, Springer-Verlag, Berlin, Heidelberg, 2008, pp. 167–177. [Available here](http://www.osti.gov/scitech/biblio/15016591)

So, for example, usage of a barrier synchronization (flush implied) for staged computations (a-la BSP) in case of inter-thread data dependencies does not provide visibility of data modifications in that case per se.

Should I use C++11 CAS operations on release-acquire (RelAcq) or sequentially consistent atomics to provide memory fences, or a set of locks (AFAIK locks are built on top of RelAcq atomics) to provide p2p synchronization with visibility guaranties?

P.S.: Is `#pragma omp atomic seq_cst` an option in case of an OpenMP 4.0?

Comment: Most shared-memory architectures nowadays are cache-coherent and on cache-coherent systems the only truly private memory is the register file in each core. Therefore `flush` on such systems usually results in some sort of a memory fence instruction for CPUs with out-of-order execution and also makes the compiler save to memory/load from memory any shared variable that has been (register-)optimised. The cache-coherency protocol takes care of the rest.

Comment: @Hristo: Could you rephrase it more clearly to me? Do all you say mean all threads actually see the results of each other after passing a barrier for example?

Comment: I cannot comment on the general semantics of the OpenMP constructs, but on x86 the answer is yes - after a barrier, all threads should have the same view of the shared data.

Comment: @Hristo: If I understood it correctly (just to broaden your answer), at least for x86 in case we ensure that flush with an empty flush-set (empty flush hereafter) of a producer thread completes before an empty flush of a consumer thread all _memory modifications_ of a producer should be visible to a consumer thread (in case there is no intervening third-party thread)? And such additional machinery as atomic CAS, mutexes, barriers and critical sections are there solely for sequencing threads in time (not taking in account implied empty flushes) in that case.

Comment: @Hristo: AFAIK the barrier implementation in a runtime-library is based on CAS ops. and mem fences in such a way, that there is a sequencing of mem. ops before committing the 'may pass barrier' flag, which every interested thread should see before passing the barrier (as of GCC). So, flush is a conceptual thing, whose implementation depends on an OpenMP construct used.